# Callback-return value doesn't get stored in a HTTP-request (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js

I have set up a server-application with NodeJS/Express and am trying to get the following script to work so that it stores the return value of a http-request in a variable for later use.

```
function checkIfVerified(req, res) {
var user_id = req.user.id

var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://MYDOMAIN/api/v2/users/' + user_id + '?fields=email_verified&include_fields=true',
    headers:
        {
            authorization: 'Bearer ' + app.locals.token
        },
    body:
        {

        },
    json: true
}

function check(callback) {
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        return callback(null, body)
    })
}
var email_verified = check(function (err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        return data
    }
})
console.log(email_verified)
return email_verified
}
```

For some reason the variable 'email_verified' doesn't hold any value ...

Thanks for your help!
Cheers
Philip

Comment: when you are using callbacks, this is because the call is `async` so it will not return any value, but a promise.

Comment: Ok thanks - is there a way to turn the promise into a value? Or is there a way to extract the "body"-data out of the request without a callback? I know that there's something like promise.resolve, but that would not return the value itself right?

Answer (score 0):

So after @Derlins clue I found out the following solution to the question:

```
function check() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error)
      } else {
        resolve(body.email_verified)
      }
    })
  })
}
res.locals.email_verified = await check()
```

This does the trick :-)